# Book publishing or a peer review journal

Tags: publications

I have written lately, a theory about the whole existence. Do you guys think that I should publish my writings as a self-publishing book or aim for peer-review and publish in a journal?.
Keeping in mind that I want my writing to have an impact 
I am an engineer, specialized in classic physics, my writing contains concepts of time, gravity, elementary particles, cosmic inflation, gravitational collapse, and lensing.

Comment: Nobody reads self-published books about "the whole existence", at least not from a scientific audience. Try peer reviewed journals, but don't fall for predatory open access. Good luck.

Comment: Who is your intended audience?

Comment: Thank henning, Dear Astronaut, I want the whole world to see my perspective on existence.

Comment: I am not looking into profits, I just want, in case my theory turns out to be true, I want to get credited for.

Comment: FYI, in about 100 years this will sound like: "... a theory about the whole existence ... my writing contains concepts of time, magnetism, [protyle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/protyle), radiant matter, molecular change, and galvanometric effects."

Comment: Your writings are unlikely to have an impact unless you are a professional researcher in those fields. Indeed what exactly makes your writings different from any other dilettante?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing a book is not that hard, but getting people to read it is. Publishing in a journal would work, but based on the description of what you're going to write about, it seems unlikely that any reputable journal will publish it.

I'd say first get some confirmation from an expert that your ideas are correct. Try talking to [Sabine Hossenfelder](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/p/talk-to-physicist_27.html) (costs $50 for 20 minutes, which will still be cheaper than self-publishing a book). If she says your ideas are credible, then ask her how to publish them.